"NoSuchElementException" despite trying by XPATH, NAME, CLASS_NAME with Selenium and Python
I am using selenium with Python 3.7, chrome driver version 124.0.6367.91.
On the webpage for Smartplay, I am essentially trying to automate filling in the username and password.
Any suggestions for how I can input my username/password into the two fields?
I have already tried the below, but each time it results in a NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
driver.find_element(By.NAME,"pc-login-username").send_keys(username)

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"input").send_keys(username)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[@id='app']/div[@class='app-router-view']/div/div[1]/div[@class='smart-play-pc-tablet']/div/div[@class='home-pc-head']/div[@class='home-pc-head-box']/div[@class='my-input el-input']/input[@class='el-input__inner']").send_keys(username)

I have even tried to wait for the element to be present, but it seems like it is never loaded on the page:
try:
   myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.NAME,"pc-login-username")
   print ("Element is present")
except TimeoutException:
   print ("Element not found")


They have a lot of bot protection on that site including preventing you from inspecting elements to when you navigate to the URL, it bounces you off the site. That's the main reason it can't find the elements... because it ends up on a blank page.
